# minimum degree of 2-connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity, extremal-graph-theory

If we have a 2-connected graph G, then can we say that δ(G) > k(G)? I need that in order to use Halin's theorem.
Can we have then a more general relation between k-connected graphs and their minimum degree?

Comment: Take $G$ to be a cycle. Then $\delta(G)=\kappa(G)=2$

Comment: Though the question was answered. But what is Halin's theorem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every simple graph $G$: $$\delta(G)\geq\kappa(G).$$

Here's why: Take the vertex $v \in V(G)$ with $\deg(v)=\delta(G)$. Take a set $S=\{u \in V(G) | uv \in E(G)\}$. Obviously $G-S$ is disconnected. Therefore:
$$\kappa(G)\leq |S|=\delta(G).$$

So to answer your question, $\delta(G)$ and $\kappa(G)$ can also be equal.